# Custom setting ruby garbage collection variables for a rails app on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, garbage-collection

Where's the best place to custom set ruby garbage collection environment variables such as RUBY_GC_MALLOC_LIMIT for a rails app on heroku?

Answer (score 0):

Use heroku's `config:set` [API](http://snaprails.tumblr.com/post/241746095/rubys-gc-configuration):

> **Setting up config vars for a deployed application**
>
> Use the Heroku CLI’s config, `config:set`, `config:get` and `config:unset`
>   to manage your config vars:
>
> > Previous versions of the Heroku Toolbelt used `config:add` and
> >     `config:remove`
>
> ```
> $ heroku config:set GITHUB_USERNAME=joesmith
> Adding config vars and restarting myapp... done, v12
> GITHUB_USERNAME: joesmith
>
> $ heroku config
> GITHUB_USERNAME: joesmith
> OTHER_VAR:       production
>
> $ heroku config:get GITHUB_USERNAME
> joesmith
>
> $ heroku config:unset GITHUB_USERNAME
> Unsetting GITHUB_USERNAME and restarting myapp... done, v13
> ```
>
> Heroku manifests these config vars as environment variables to the
>   application. These environment variables are persistent – they will
>   remain in place across deploys and app restarts – so unless you need
>   to change values, you only need to set them once.